# Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'X' is not a valid attribute of element 'Y'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio

I quite often do this:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" quantity="2" price="15" />
```

which causes VS2010 to issue the above warning -- I can live with the warnings because the inherent value in being able to hang data on form fields (which allows me later to pick them up for use in code e.g. `$('#whatever').attr('price')`, or simply `document.getElementById('whatever').price`) makes the nuisance warnings worth bearing.  However, I was wondering what the canonical approach to this problem is...

anyone?

TIA - ekkis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can store those variables in the object itself with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$('#whatever').data('quantity', 2);
```

But I suggest splitting up your `<input />` into multiple `<input />`s if you absolutely *need* to keep the information in the HTML file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="whatever-quantity" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" id="whatever-price" value="15" />
```

But for complete HTML5 awesomeness, just prepend `data-` to your attributes:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" data-quantity="2" data-price="15" />
```

Comment: ya.  the "hidden" approach is unbearable when you have tons of stuff... and using jQuery to store the data was also unacceptable.  I wanted it to be nice and neat.  `data-` certainly does that.  awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should replace `quantity="2" price="15"` with `data-quantity="2" data-price="15"` -- which has the added bonus of making the values accessible through jQuery's `.data()` method:

```
alert( $('#whatever').data('price') ); // displays 15
```

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/